# Compatibility issues with IE7 (top margin is totally screwed)

Tags: internet-explorer, compatibility, margin

I'm new to CSS and really need some help in troubleshooting this website which I had just completed. Everything looks fine in FF, safari, chrome (opera looks ok) except IE7 (IE8 or IE9 has to be viewed in compatibility view).

The top margin is totally missing when I view it in IE browser, and that makes it out of alignment. I had tried to search for a few solutions from different sites, but no luck...

I know that the older IE has got issue with PNG files as well, and that's one of the problems (when the PNG file is used to mask some part of the image) --- it won't show up.

These images screwed up on IE7. I can't show any screencap, cuz my IE8 seems to work fine in CV mode :(

sorry for the long string of codes below, but I do not know which part of it went wrong. The live site is at www.heightprotectionsolutions.com.sg (probably easier to take a look here). Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
<body>  
<div id="container"> 

    <!-- BEGIN OF HEADER -->
    <div id="header-container">
        <div id="header-box">

            <!-- begin of logo -->
            <div id="logo">
                <a href="#"><img src="images/logo_home.png" alt="main-logo" /></a>
            </div>
            <!-- end of logo -->

            <div id="righttop-header">
                <div id="top-information">
                    <p>For additonal information call : +65 9793 2263 | fax : +65 6748 2123</p>
                </div>

                <!-- begin of mainmenu -->
                <div id="mainmenu">
                    <ul id="menu">
                        <li><a href="index.html">home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="about.html">about</a></li>
                        <li><a href="services.html">services</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">products</a>
                            <ul> 
                                <li><a href="GFP.html">GFP</a></li>
                                <li><a href="innotech.html">Innotech</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="current"><a href="partners.html">partners</a></li>
                        <li><a href="contact.html">contact</a></li>
                    </ul>                
              </div>
                <!-- end of mainmenu -->                    
            </div>

        </div>            
    </div>
    <!-- BEGIN OF HEADER -->

    <!-- BEGIN OF SLIDESHOW -->
    <div id="slideshow-container">
        <div id="slide-top"></div>            
        <ul id="slider">
            <!-- begin of slide 1 -->
            <li>
            <div class="slide-content-wrapper">                             
                <div class="slide-content">                        
                    <div class="slide-text">
                        <h1>Uncompromised Safety.</h1>
                        <p>The Trusted Safety Lifeline</p>
                        <a class="button small yellow" href="contact.html"><span>get a quote &nbsp;&raquo;</span></a>
                    </div>                                    
                </div>
                <div class="slide-dot"></div>
            </div>
            <img src="images/slideshow/slide1.jpg" alt="" />
            </li>
            <!-- end of slide 1 -->
```

Here's the CSS codes. Not sure if I must set a fixed margin for IE7 to display properly, just like the rest of the browsers?

```
#container{ 
margin:0px 0px 0px 0px; 
}
#header-container{
width:100%;
}
#header-box{
width:1090px;
margin:0px auto;
#header-box{
margin:50px auto 0px auto;
}   
}
#slideshow-container{
width:1090px;   
margin:30px auto 48px auto;
}
#headerimage-container{
width:1090px;   
margin:48px auto 0px auto;
}
#slide-top, #headerimage-top{
width:1090px;
height:99px;
background-image:url(../images/bg-top-slide2.png);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
position:absolute;
z-index:100;
float:left;
```